# PostgreSQL with Homebrew on Mac

Tags: postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

First I use homebrew and install postgresql and I get this success message:

> ==> Summary   /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2: 2819 files, 39M, built in 68 seconds

Then I need to run this command:

```
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres -E utf8
```

But this is the message I get:
What should I do with this?
Also running on OSX 10.8.2

> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user
>   "JonyIve". This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
>   The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty If
>   you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty the
>   directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb with an argument
>   other than "/usr/local/var/postgres".

Comment: Usually PG uses data directories beneath the installation directory. For example, on Windows the default directory is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data`. What is under your /usr/local/var/postgres directory?

Comment: To anyone who sets up PostgreSQL on MacOS, this may give you guidance: https://www.robinwieruch.de/postgres-sql-macos-setup

Answer (score 47):

Assuming this is a new installation and not a re-installation I think solving your problem is as simple as:

```
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres/data -E utf8
```

Typically the data directory is called "data' and is underneath the postgresql home directory.  this allows for the possibility of sharing log file access and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you can do this without breaking anything, another option is always just to remove the directory as per the message

> remove or empty the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"

Via

`rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`