# Postgresql version 13 psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos-mojave

I'm currently working with a Rails 6 application and Postgresql. I been having issues when I run `rails db:create`. This error seem to happen after I updated `brew upgrade` I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'm running Mac OS Mojave and I updated postgresq to version 13.

```
$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.0
```

I'm guessing this is why I have issues, I noticed in some of the other posts that running  `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` might be a FIX to this problem, however when I run the command I get:

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/var/postgres/PG_VERSION
```

But I can see the `.old` file when I navigate to `postgres` as shown in the image below:
[image]

Also, if I tried connecting to `psql` I get an error

```
$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I also see that the service is running:

```
$ ps -ef | grep postgres
  501 48733  5971   0  1:23PM ttys011    0:00.31 /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-166_1/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim /usr/local/var/postgres/
  501 52975  5971   0  1:54PM ttys011    0:00.01 grep postgres
```

What can the issue be?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? It sounds like it's just not listening. Try this: `telnet localhost 5432`. If it fails, it's definitely *not* running on that port. Also, check `/var/log/postgres` for any errors. In any case, it's worth trying a reboot first.

Comment: ```Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host```

Answer (score 3):

this fixed it for me

```
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres/data -E utf8
```

and then running

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data -l logfile start
```

Follow [PostgreSQL with Homebrew on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510237/postgresql-with-homebrew-on-mac/16159948) for more detail